# Is it legal to use a logo as profile picture?

Tags: support, profile-picture

Would it be okay if I change my profile picture to, e.g. the windows or the google logo? Or is this illegal?

Comment: [MSE dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176253/294055)

Comment: No, but very likely nobody would care.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a legal issue that is not specific to SO.

Comment: @honk The MSE dupe got 12 ups. This question is now at -7. While they are dupes. Uhm... no further comment.

Comment: @peterh: I didn't vote on either of them. However, the dupe was easy to find, so maybe other users downvoted because of lack of research. But I'm only guessing...

Comment: @honk I think it is very nice if 9 people until now all searched for a cross-site dupe, and all of them found it, and voted down this question on this reason. They should be very conscient reviewers.

Answer (score 9):

The content you provide on the site needs to be your own or the image needs to have a license that allows you to copy and distribute.

I don't think you own the copyright or are the owner of the logo's you mention. Although you will not be prevented from changing your profile image to said logo's you might have to deal with the consequences of doing so, which might include legal action from the owners of the copyright.

Stack Exchange might receive a [DMCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Millennium_Copyright_Act) request to take down / remove the image, causing your profile picture to be reset to the default.

For more details I suggest you read the [Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal) and the answers from Emil Vikström and Gilles on [Profile Images with copyright](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176256)

<sup>Disclaimer: I'm not an lawyer, don't accept legal advice from strangers on the internet</sup>